# Sheaf cohomology; global sections of $\Omega_X^1$

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

The setting is quite simple: Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface and $\omega$ is a holomorphic 1-form i.e. $\omega \in \Omega_X^1$. Then we can write $\omega = df$ for a holomorphic function $f:X \to \mathbb{C}$.

1. Question 1: since $\omega \in \Omega_X^1$ is it ok to say that $[\omega]\in H^1(X,\mathbb{C})$? That is it is an exact holomorphic form.
2. I read that there is an **injective map** $H^0(X, \Omega_X^1) \to H^1(X,\mathbb{C})$. The classes of the latter cohomology  give equivalence classes of holomorphic 1-forms. What are the classes of the former cohomology $H^0(X, \Omega_X^1)$?

I see that the coefficients must be holomorphic one forms but I cannot understand what a representative of this class looks like (locally or globally). Usually the zero cohomology gives us information about the global sections so what can we understand from the information above?

Comment: There seem to be several points of confusion in your question, but perhaps the first is that in general we can't write $\omega$ in the form $df$ (contrary to your assertion).

Comment: @tracing I assume $\omega$ is exact. Sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: If $X$ is a connected  compact Riemann surface then there are no non-constant holomorphic functions, so in your set-up, $f$ is constant and so $df = 0$.  In fact it is a general result that a non-zero holomorphic one-form on a connected compact Riemann surface is never exact, which is why the map $H^0(X,\Omega^1_X) \to H^0(X,\mathbb C)$ is injective.  On the other hand, this map is *not* surjective (unless the genus is $0$, in which case both sides are $0$) and so it is not true that the $H^1(X,\mathbb C)$ gives equivalence class of holomorphic $1$-forms.

Comment: @tracing thanks. So what you are saying is that in the setting above the only globally defined holomorphic functions are the constant functions and as a result $df=0$. Then in the globally defined holomorphic 1-forms $H^0(X,\Omega_X^1)$ map to globally defined holomorphic functions $H^0(X,\mathbb{C})$. Is this a correct interpretation? (I am a physics major so I am sloppy with the coefficients, actually this is part of the question, what are elements of each cohomology group). By the way I got this question from https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1803v3.pdf page 70.

Comment: In your last comment you wrote $H^0(X,\mathbb C)$, which means the *locallly constant* complex-valued functions on $X$.  When $X$ is connected (as it is in your set-up) this is just one-dimensional.  What you wrote in your question, and what I wrote in my comment, is $H^1(X,\mathbb  C)$ --- this is cohom. in degree $1$ with complex coefficients, which can be computed in various ways, e.g. via a triangulation of $X$, or (more immediately relevant here) via de Rham theory: it is closed smooth $1$-forms (allowing complex numbers as scalars) modulo exact smooth $1$-forms.

Comment: Since holomorphic $1$-forms are automatically closed, and cannot be exact (unless they are zero), we get an injection $H^0(X,\Omega^1_X) \to H^1(X,\mathbb C)$.   Note that if $X$ has genus $g$, then the source of this map has dimension $g$ (as a $\mathbb C$-vector space), and the target has dimension $2g$.  If you're unsure about these things, there are many references, e.g. Griffiths and Harris will discuss this (as will many other sources).

Comment: @tracing thanks, indeed it was a typo in my comment, I meant to have degree $1$ in the cohomology $H^1(X,\mathbb{C})$. I do get now this injection but I lack interpretation. What I mean: I see  $H^1(X,\mathbb{C})$ and 1-forms on this space can be written as $f(z,\bar{z}) = cdz$ or $f(z,\bar{z})=c' d\bar{z}$, correct? On the other hand  $H^0(X,\Omega_X^1)$ are the globally defined holomorphic 1-forms, is this correct? Indeed, Griffiths and Harris has a lot of information as well as other sources but this is why I ask questions, here, to clear up things I read on the books.